# Where can I see what Piloting Skill level I need to fly a specific space ship?

Tags: starfield

I have found this space ship:

[image]

How can I see what "Piloting Skill" level I need to set this space ship as my new "Home Ship" (pressing <kbd>H</kbd>) and fly it?

Currently I can not switch to it because of lacking "Fliegen-Skill".
*(I play the German version and I'm not sure, what skill exactly I need.)*

Could it be that I have to achieve a higher level on the flight simulator first?
*(I only have reached level 4 (of 6) so far.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to level up the [Piloting skill](https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Piloting) in the Tech tree.

It's based on the ship class, which I believe in your screenshot is class "B" (the reactor designation).  The order of class goes:

- A (lowest)
- B
- C (highest)

The Piloting Perk's third rank unlocks the ability to pilot class B ships.  The fourth rank unlocks the ability to pilot class C ships. The class is determined by what [reactor](https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Reactor) a ship has.

Comment: I must have been blind. There is a **B** in front of the reactor value 27. According to my Piloting Skill tree, I have to get rank 3 to fly this kind of space ship. Thanks for this hint

Comment: @PeterCo yup its based on the ships reactor.  I learned that the hard way trying to upgrade a reactor on my one ship only for it to yell at me saying I don't have the pilot level to fly the ship after making the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [answer of @Timm-Jim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404493/54377) I eventually found the reactor class too:

[image]